# Lock cell range when certain cell reach zero

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula

I need to figure out a way to prevent people from adding values if a certain cell reaches zero.
I have thousands of t-shirts to distribute among several locations, and I want people to type in the amount they need, however, I only have a certain number of t-shirts produced, so the idea is to prevent people from ordering them if the stock level reaches zero.
e.g I have 40 Large tees in cell C3 in cells C4:C9 I allow people from the offices to type in their desired quantity, as it is a first come first served basis if someone from one location orders all of them I want to get other cells blocked/locked and maybe greyed out.

is this doable in Excel, or Google Spreadsheet?

thanks!

Comment: Welcome. Your question is too vague *(feels like a teacher's scenario)*. Please read how to and [share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311) so as you can be easier helped.

Comment: Hi @marikamitsos
Yes, you are right. Apologies for this, here is the test spreadsheet:

the solution that jsheeran posted below works but only with columns, and not rows. 
Thanks so much for any suggestions on this.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eh3WPPQa-XXgmCTD6TzttDUU76h_zBaeEvfJpJj6tBk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @DonDenar There is a solution for your offices. Please let me know when you're back.

Comment: Still interested for a solution as per your sheet? If so let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use data validation.

1. Select the range C4:C9. On the ribbon, select **Data > Data Validation**.
2. Select "Custom" and enter the formula `=SUM($C$4:$C$9)<=$C$3`.
   [image]
3. Optionally, open the "Error Alert" tab and provide a custom message to be shown to users when they try to exceed the value in C3.